# Mac OS | xmlXPathCompOpEval: function max bound to undefined prefix math

Tags: objective-c, macos, math, libxml2, libxslt

In my application, i am using libxslt engine, and stucked in one issue, my xslt engine having one syntax is using

```
<xsl:value-of select="math:max(x)"/>
```

and getting warning

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function max bound to undefined prefix math
```

does that mean, existing libxslt doesn't support math function on OSX and what are all other alternative to resolve this errors.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, i need to have latest libxslt and libexslt 
adding to that, it also needs to have proper Namespace in the xsl file.